# Linq to SQL, many to many design

Tags: c#, sql, linq-to-sql

I'm trying to take an object and design an SQL table to store it.  The object has a member called "Roles" which is an enum that has 4 values.  Each object can have several different roles.

Right now, I've taken the enum and created an eponymously named SQL table out of it and added the 4 roles to it.  Now I'm trying to design the object table and I can't figure out how to get the many to many relationship working for it.  I would also like it to work well with Linq-to-SQL.  It would be nice to have the enum preserved, but if not an array of strings could also work.

In short, I need a table that has a many-to-many between Roles and Object.Roles (or Object.Roles[])

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Generally, Many-To-Many relationships in Linq2SQL (and Entity Framework) are created by introducing an *association table*, with only the primary keys from the two tables you want to link, and where each row corresponds to an association.

Since your `Role` and `Object.Role` could be difficult to keep apart in an attempt to explain this, I'll give another example: in a school, each teacher can have many students, and each student can have many teachers. The table structure to represent this would then be

```
Teachers                    Students                     StudentTeacherRelations
********                    ********                     ***********************
TeacherId                   StudentId                    TeacherId
FirstName                   FirstName                    StudentId
etc...                      etc...
```

Now, Linq2SQL and EF are both smart enough to recognize this as a many-to-many relationship, and introduce navigation properties in your model. A POCO with appropriate properties for the Student object could look like this:

```
public class Student
{
    public int StudentId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    // etc
    public IEnumerable<Teacher> Teachers { get; }
}
```

If this is set up correctly, the O/R mapper will automatically populate the `Teachers` property.

**Update:** In response to comments, here is a how I'd structure the rest of the database if I wanted to include a scenario where each teacher can give some students homework consisting of a number of questions:

```
HomeworkAssignments          Questions                      Answers
*******************          *********                      *******
HomeworkAssignmentId (pk)    QuestionId (pk)                AnswerId (pk)
...                          HomeworkAssignmentId (fk)      QuestionId (fk)
                             ...                            StudentId (fk)
                                                            ...

StudentHomeworkAssignmentRelations    TeacherHomeworkAssignmentRelations
**********************************    **********************************
StudentId (fk)                        Teacherid (fk)
HomeworkAssignmentId (fk)             HomeworkAssignmentId (fk)
```

As you can see, there's quite a lot of tables here. However, this structure allows you to let each teacher create many homework assignments, and then hand each assignment out to a number of students. You'll have a navigational property `Student.HomeworkAssignments` of type `IEnumerable<HomeworkAssignment>`, via which you can find all the questions a student has to answer. For each posted answer, you store a row in the `Answers` table, which is linked to both questions and students by 1-to-many relations - each answer can belong to one question only, and be given by one student only.

The key here is that you don't need to be able to access each answer given by a student directly - in both Linq2SQL and EF it's possible to request data from many tables at once in various ways. One of those ways is

```
var answersToTheLastExam = context.Students
                  .SelectMany(s => s.HomeworkAssignments)
                  .OrderBy(ha => ha.Date) // this might need modifying to get the last one first
                  .First(ha => ha.Questions.Count() > 0)
                  .SelectMany(ha => ha.Questions)
                  .SelectMany(q => q.Answers)
                  .Where(a => a.StudentId == myId)
```

*Note that this code is untested an might not work as I say it will. I'm just trying my best off the top of my head here =)*

Comment: Thanks! I have a follow up question. Lets say I take it one step further and say that in your example each Teacher gives 25 `HomeWorks` each with 50 `Questions`, and now each student has not only an m-to-m with the Teacher, but now with each `HomeWorks`. And lets say we want to record what each student got correct on each `HomeWorks` (per question, not just 34/36). For this example, lets say `HomeWorks` has an association with one Teacher and a one-to-many with `Questions`. What would be the best way to get a Student with all the `HomeWorks`, Teachers and `Questions`?

Comment: More on the comment above.  Lets say one student has 3 Teachers.  That would mean that that one Student would have a total of 3750 `Questions` records for just him.  This seems like a lot, is there a better way of handling this situation?

Comment: In a well-indexed database, the number of records can reach tens of millions in a single table without being a problem, so 3750 is really nothing to worry about. (However, if you start approaching millions of records, consider rebuilding your indexes on a regular basis during low intensity periods...) For the general homeworks structure, see my edit (which I'll start writing now...)

Comment: Thank you very much!  You were very thorough with your example and answered my question completely.

Answer (score 0):

Roles
Id Pk

ObjectRoles
Id Pk

ObjectRoleRoles
RolesId Pk & FK
ObjectRolesId PK & FK

```
           var result = (from orr in _context.ObjectRoleRoles
                         inner join r in _context.Roles on orr.RolesId equals r.Id
                         inner join or in _context.ObjectRoles on orr.ObjectRolesId equals or.Id
                         where orr.RolesId equals 1
                         select r).ToList();
```

The fields in ObjectRoleRoles must be both the PK and FK.